# Backup wireless connections and passwords on Debian Squeeze

Tags: wireless-networking, backup, debian

Well, it's pretty self-explanatory from the title. I'm redoing (formatting and installing various OS's on) my laptop for a variety of reasons. Since I've connected to a lot of different wifi AP's over time, I'd like to be able to save those connections to carry over to my new setup. I'm switching to a dual-boot setup with Ubuntu 12.04 and WindowsXP, so if there's a way to recover the plain-text passwords, that's fine and I can enter them myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

network-manager based;

```
tar caf my_networking.tar.gz ~/.gconf/system/networking/
```

and for the passwords in the gnome-keyring;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk # sets app name
import gnomekeyring

def hack():
    for keyring in gnomekeyring.list_keyring_names_sync():
        for id in gnomekeyring.list_item_ids_sync(keyring):
            item = gnomekeyring.item_get_info_sync(keyring, id)
            print '[%s] %s = %s' % (
                    keyring, item.get_display_name(), item.get_secret())
        else:
            if len(gnomekeyring.list_item_ids_sync(keyring)) == 0:
                print '[%s] --empty--' % keyring

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hack()
```

Comment: Thank you. After your answer, I went researching about backing up the plain-text passphrases and found a python script that will list the passwords in the gnome-keyring. It's a little out-dated though and doesn't work, but I'll pick at it a little bit. I didn't mark it answered yet because I'm still trying to get the passphrases backed up, but your answer helps a lot.

Comment: just looked at this one and ran it here.. works perfectly :: http://blog.schmichael.com/2008/10/30/listing-all-passwords-stored-in-gnome-keyring/

Comment: Ok, cool. I think I'm missing a dependency on it, since it failed at line 6. I'll look at it. Thanks.

Comment: make sure the formating is exact, python has to have its indents all in the right places, lol picky language

Comment: apt-get install python-gnomekeyring     ;)